# Updating tables based on Oracle JDBC Database Change Notification

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, notifications

How to get change notifications for rows updated such as row data/row description. I am able to get rows Id's which are updated.

I need to sync Table1 with Table2 based on the row Id's that I get as notification after updating Table1. I have read on few sites about notifications, but couldn't find any information on how to update a table based on notification. Please help!!

**Below is some help information I found on Oracle [website](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm)**:

> Applications in the middle tier require rapid access to cached copies
>   of database objects while keeping the cache as current as possible in
>   relation to the database. Cached data becomes out of date or "stale"
>   when a transaction modifies the data and commits, thereby putting the
>   application at risk of accessing incorrect results. If the application
>   uses Database Change Notification, then Oracle Database can publish a
>   notification when a change occurs to registered objects with details
>   on what changed.
>
> In response to the notification, the application can refresh cached
>   data by fetching it from the back-end database.

Comment: `Table1` and `Table2`, presumably, refer to tables in databases, right?  Not to a table in a user-interface.  Are `Table1` and `Table2` both in an Oracle database?  Are they in the same Oracle database?  Or different Oracle databases?  Is there a reason that you are not using one of the built-in replication solutions that Oracle ships with in favor of writing your own custom code?

Comment: Yes they are tables in Database. For now they are in same same database, but the actual scenario would change later to different types of databases across multiple platforms

Comment: There are replication technologies that do that already (for example Oracle's Golden Gate)-- I'd be very hesitant to try to build that sort of technology from the ground up yourself.  Are you trying to allow just `Table2` to be on a non-Oracle databases?  Or to allow `Table1` as well to be on a non-Oracle datbase?

Comment: Only one table would vary in regards to database type

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand what you mean.  I think you may be saying that the source table `Table1` will always reside in an Oracle database but that the destination table `Table2` may reside in either an Oracle database or a non-Oracle database.  If that's the case, I'd still be using one of the built-in replication technologies rather than trying to write your own.

Comment: I know there may be other solutions to this, but I have to implement this in java from ground up as part of the project at work so I am looking for java based solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Application Developer's Guide you cited](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm) I note that about the sixth paragraph under the "Developing Applications with Database Change Notification" states:

> The notification contains only metadata about the changed rows or objects rather than the changed data itself.

So there doesn't appear to be a way to get Oracle to tell you that `FIELD_X` or `DESCRIPTION` or whatever changed. Once the change notification is received which tells you the table and the ROWID you need to go out and fetch the data which was altered (if that's appropriate), and update the cached copy.

Your mileage may vary.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: How do I create a cached copy?

Comment: One table (in this case it appears to be Table1) is the source table, and Table2 appears to be the cache, if I'm understanding the text of your question correctly. In this case I'd suggest creating a trigger on Table1 which fires on insert, update, or delete and which update Table2 to match what's now in Table1. Best of luck.