# inbuilt cache mechanism in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching, jdbc

I have to cache the oracle database change notifications and query results and use it to update another table in another oracle database. Answers to my previous [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744705/updating-tables-based-on-oracle-jdbc-database-change-notification/27745030#27745030) suggested me to use cache and I am not sure if there is a inbuilt cache mechanism in java or I have to use some external framework/library to achieve this?

Note: I am using oracle jdbc to fetch the results.

For example: If a user updates the table manually through sql developer or through command prompt then the resulting [**change-notifications**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28816) coming from oracle database should be cached.

Comment: Both the database and the OS should already be caching the query. I'm unsure why you're looking to cache externally at all. Do you need to transfer data to a second database? Don't over-complicate unless you _really_ have to.

Comment: Yes I need to transfer the data to second database. What do you mean by "Both the database and the OS should already be caching the query"? If they are already caching the query then how should get hold of it programatically in java - any sample would help. Thanks

Comment: If I have transfer the data to second database then I need to cache the query results right ?

Comment: You can't get the results. So, the cache in question, according to your previous question, is the second database. You've already created it, so don't need to do anything. If you have already transferred the data then you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Can you give more clarity? I have not used any cache mechanism if you read previous question thoroughly and that's why the users have suggested me to go for cache mechanism.

Comment: Bob Jarvis described your second DB as the cache, which makes sense. You receive the change notification, grab the row and then update your second DB. I'm not sure you understand why you're doing this, which you really should before implementing it. It might be worth getting a bit of code working based on what you already _know_ (rather than have been told) and see what isn't working.

Comment: Oh god.. If I have already transferred the data then why would I post the question here. Did you read my question properly? Have I mentioned anywhere that I have already transferred the data to second database

Comment: Your comment stated that. If I'm misreading it then it doesn't matter...

Comment: @kittu Maybe you should take some time to edit your question(s) in order to explain your _use case_. At first sight, all of this sounds much more like _"replication"_ than _"catching"_. But as I said, for now this isn't really clear to me.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux No way its sounds like replication as I have clearly mentioned I want to "cache the query results" not replication so please stop imagining out of the question.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Use case is already mentioned. Take your time to read the question again and also my previous question provided as a hyperlink. My actual question is about "inbuilt caching mechanism in java" but the comments are going off-topic unnecessarily

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I read that link already. It talks about resultSet caching in java program but what about if a user updates the table through command prompt? then the result won't get cached.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I appreciate you are trying to help. I have posted question here only when I couldn't find an answer after hours of search on web. If you know what I am looking for..then please help else leave it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Have a look at the updated question. The link you have provided is great and I have already seen it but the implementation example in the same link is _querying through java program only_ - which doesn't suit in real time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in caching mechanism in the Java JDBC API *per se*.

The Oracle JDBC driver (apparently) supports client-side caching of result sets, but I don't see how that helps:

- It caches resultsets, not inserts and deletes.
- It only caches queries / resultsets done by the current client JVM, not anything done from other client JVMs ... or other kinds of client.
- AFAIK, there is no public API for checking what has been cached, and you would need that if you were to use the cache for mirroring updates.

In fact, I don't think that caching is the right approach at all.  Caches have finite size, and throw out (evict) old entries.  A cache is (typically) not aware that something else is depending on entries NOT being evicted until they have been mirrored.  Hence, I would expect a cache-based solution to loose updates if they happen faster than they can be mirrored.

---

I think that the best approach would be to set up Oracle database replication on the server side.  There are reams of Oracle documentation on this ... and I'm not an expert.

Client-side replication using "ha-jdbc" (or similar) would work in some cases.  However, all of the database clients would need to use the library, and that is precluded in your use-case.

Finally, it may be possible to implement a replicator that uses Oracle database update notifications.  However it looks complicated and potentially expensive.  (I'd expect Oracle's native replication to be more performant.)

Comment: "*It only caches queries done by the current client JVM*" - Oracle also supports a server side query cache.

Comment: But it is still just a QUERY cache?  Correct?

Comment: yes, and I don't see any reason to cache anything else. What's the point of caching inserts and deletes? The result of the query is cached, if anything changes in the underlying tables, the query cache will be invalidated and the next time the query is run it re-populates the cache (that is true for the server side cache **and** the client side cache). If you cache inserts and deletes you need to manually re-implement the whole database logic of inserts and deletes on the client side as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - The point is that the OP wants to replicate updates to another database.  Now I don't think that caching is the right approach at all ... and the fact that it makes no sense to cache inserts / deletes supports my argument.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Your comment is somewhat I am looking for. I want to cache inserts and deletes as well. When a user updates the tables through command prompt for say, the resulting DBChangenotification(Change Events) I have to cache in java program. Now comes the point whether I have to use server-side cache or client-side? If I use server-side cache then I guess DBChangenotifications would not make any sense.

Comment: @kittu: you ***are*** looking for a replication solution then. You could use bi-directional replication through materialized views or Oracle streams to achieve this. There are also several commercial tools to do that. But please stop calling it *caching* it **is** replication you are looking for.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When you say "replicate" I get the feeling of cloning in java. Actually I want to maintain sync between tables in different databases through java implementation. When I say "sync", any update or delete should be refreshed/added to cache(rowId's returned from DBChangeNotification) and I will use that cache to update other table

Comment: @kittu: That is the precise definition of "replication" in the database world. Why re-invent the wheel (in Java) if you get that for free directly in the database? There are some projects that already did something like this, e.g.: https://ha-jdbc.github.io/

Comment: @ha-jdbc.github.io But I am looking for an answer in java world my friend and that is my requirement of the project.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Shall I paste some of my program code for more clarity?

Comment: @kittu: I gave you the link of a replication (an open source) library implemented in Java. What else are you looking for? If you already have code then you should post _that_ code (in a new question) explaining why it doesn't work for you and what the problem is you have with it.

Comment: The link is of no use my friend if you read my comments properly. Any way I post a new question with bit of code. Thanks ;)